# `assumeIsolated(_:)` fails with DispatchSerialQueue as custom Executor in Actor

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, actor, swift-concurrency

I want to implement an actor which uses "legacy" components which are classes using a dispatch queue for calling callbacks.

These "legacy" components are actually classes from Apples NWNetwork framework. These classes require a dispatch queue and callback functions to be specified. The callback functions will be called by the framework on the specified dispatch queue.

What I want to avoid is, to implement the callbacks like:

```
    @Sendable
    nonisolated
    private func callback(to newState: NWListener.State) {
        Task {
            await self.send(.listenerStateChange(newState))
        }
    }
```

i.e. dispatching into a Task which runs on the isolated context.

Instead, I want to run the whole actor on a custom Executor - a `SerialDispatchQueue` - which is also the queue for the "legacy" components.

Then, my actor provides the callback function as a member function like:

```
    @Sendable
    nonisolated
    private func callback(to newState: NWListener.State) {
        dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(self.queue))

        self.assumeIsolated { thisActor in
            thisActor.send(.listenerStateChange(newState))
        }
    }
```

The callback function must be `@Sendable` and `nonisolated`. Due to the design, it's guaranteed that the callback function is called on the given dispatch queue `self.queue`.

Now, when executing the actor, I get the following runtime error when executing `self.assumeIsolated(:_)`:

```
Fatal error: Incorrect actor executor assumption; Expected same executor as MyLib.TestActor.
```

I wrote a minimal test to demonstrate the issue:

```
public final actor TestActor {
    let queue = DispatchSerialQueue(label: "test_actor_queue")
 
    nonisolated
    public var unownedExecutor: UnownedSerialExecutor {
        queue.asUnownedSerialExecutor()
    }
    
    func isolatedFunc() {
        self.preconditionIsolated()
    }
    
    @Sendable
    nonisolated
    func nonIsolatedFunc() {
        self.queue.async {
            self.callback()
        }
    }
    
    @Sendable
    nonisolated
    func callback() {
        dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(queue))

        self.assumeIsolated { this in    // <== Runtime error
            this.isolatedFunc()
        }
    }

}
```

##### Test

```
final class HTTPServerTests: XCTestCase {
    
    func testExample() async throws {
        let actor = TestActor()
        
        await actor.isolatedFunc()
        actor.nonIsolatedFunc()
        
    }
}
```

The statement `await actor.isolatedFunc()` runs OK as expected.

`actor.nonIsolatedFunc()` simply simulates the "legacy" framework to call the callback on the specified dispatch queue. It fails during runtime with the given error.

#### Stack trace

The stack trace at the time of the runtime error also clearly shows, that we are running on the specified dispatch queue - as expected:

```
Thread 4 Queue : test_actor_queue (serial)
#0  0x000000019326df68 in _swift_runtime_on_report ()
#1  0x000000019330614c in _swift_stdlib_reportFatalErrorInFile ()
#2  0x0000000192fcb2d8 in _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) ()
#3  0x00000002099cb298 in Actor.assumeIsolated<τ_0_0>(_:file:line:) ()
#4  0x00000001053a2918 in TestActor.callback@Sendable () at /Users/agrosam/Developer/HTTPServer-NWNetwork-Actor/HTTPServer/Sources/HTTPServer/HTTPServer.swift:77
#5  0x00000001053a27a0 in closure #1 in TestActor.nonIsolatedFunc@Sendable () at /Users/agrosam/Developer/HTTPServer-NWNetwork-Actor/HTTPServer/Sources/HTTPServer/HTTPServer.swift:68
#6  0x00000001053a2978 in thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed @Sendable () -> () ()
```

My understanding is, that DispatchLib already implemented everything to have a `DispatchSerialQueue` as a well behaving citizen of a `SerialExecutor` in the actor's realm.

**So, I would expect, the runtime assertion would succeed.**

#### See also:

https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0424-custom-isolation-checking-for-serialexecutor.md

Comment: It would appear that [SE-0424](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0424-custom-isolation-checking-for-serialexecutor.md) has been implemented, but not yet deployed.

Comment: @Rob Yes, it seems like. I should have checked this. Most recent commits are a few days ago and the current snapshot (2024-03-28) does not compile as well.